# Google API send coordinates and get address with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, geocoding

Is it possible to send lat/lng and get the address? I know this is possible the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Googled it. (Should have done that before asking)

Source:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```